# Version Control Churn Job Time out

Tags: sql-server, tfs

i am getting JOB Time error on My local TFS Server 2013

it would be great if any have any idea how to short it out
Since last 1 week i am getting this JOB time Out error

```
[15837956] [TEAM FOUNDATION]MyOffice:Version Control Code Churn
    Result: Failed
    Priority:   7
    Queued Reasons: Scheduled
    Host:   [TEAM FOUNDATION]MyOffice
    Job Name:   Version Control Code Churn
    Agent:  [TFS-NYM] w3wp.exe
    Queue Time: Friday, February 24, 2017 11:00 AM
    Queue Duration: 0:00:01.18
    Start Time: Friday, February 24, 2017 11:00 AM
    Run Duration:   1:00:00.91
    End Time:   Friday, February 24, 2017 12:00 PM
    Result Message: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.DatabaseOperationTimeoutException: TF246018: The database operation exceeded the timeout limit and has been cancelled. Verify that the parameters of the operation are correct. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The wait operation timed out --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData() at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData() at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior) at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TeamFoundationSqlResourceComponent.Execute(ExecuteType executeType, CommandBehavior behavior) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TeamFoundationSqlResourceComponent.TranslateException(Int32 errorNumber, SqlException sqlException, SqlError sqlError) at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TeamFoundationSqlResourceComponent.TranslateException(SqlException sqlException) at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TeamFoundationSqlResourceComponent.MapException(SqlException ex, QueryExecutionState queryState) at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TeamFoundationSqlResourceComponent.HandleException(Exception exception) at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TeamFoundationSqlResourceComponent.Execute(ExecuteType executeType, CommandBehavior behavior) at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TeamFoundationSqlResourceComponent.ExecuteReader() at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.PropertyComponent5.GetPropertyValue(ArtifactSpecDbPagingManager dbPagingManager, IEnumerable`1 propertyNameFilters, ArtifactKind artifactKind, GetPropertiesOptions options) at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.CommandGetArtifactPropertyValue.ExecuteInternal(ArtifactKind artifactKind, IEnumerable`1 propertyNameFilters, ArtifactSpecDbPagingManager dbPagingManager, GetPropertiesOptions options) at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TeamFoundationPropertyService.GetProperties(TeamFoundationRequestContext requestContext, Guid kind, IEnumerable`1 propertyNameFilters) at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Server.CommandQueryChurnItemPairs.Execute() at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Server.TeamFoundationVersionControlService.GetFailedItemPairs(TeamFoundationRequestContext requestContext) at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.JobService.Extensions.Core.CodeChurnJobExtension.Run(TeamFoundationRequestContext requestContext, TeamFoundationJobDefinition jobDefinition, DateTime jobQueueTime, String& resultMessage)
```

Comment: What does the hardware for your data tier look like? How large are your databases? How much code is in there?

Comment: @DanielMann hi the database it self not that heavy I can execute complex query Wich returns result set in 10 to 15 second

Comment: That doesn't answer the questions I asked. The speed at which your queries execute is not relevant to the discussion. What's relevant is whether your data tier is powerful enough to support running the queries that TFS executes.

Comment: @DanielMann yes it good as per my knowledge other jobs are working fine except this one, I am curious about what could be the reason to getting fail this job

Comment: @DanielMann the TFS database servers are on VM

Comment: Did you check if there are any related  error info  in the **Event View** on your local TFS server? And also give a try with free more virtual memory on the VM which holding your TFS database

Comment: Yes I did it but the same error job fail after time out